# Constant set using define() not working in included PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code inside of my header

```
<?php 
    define('RELPATH','http://www.saint57records.com/');
    include_once(RELPATH.'sidebar.php'); 
?>
```

and an example line of code in the sidebar

```
<a href="/"><img style="margin:10px;" src="<?php print RELPATH;?>images/logo.png" width="60px"/></a>
```

but when it gets to the page it includes the file correctly but all the links inside of the file just print RELPATH instead of the web url like this

```
<a href="/"><img style="margin:10px;" src="RELPATHimages/logo.png" width="60px"/></a>
```

It works fine on the other pages of my website, just not inside of Wordpress. Does anyone know what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is to provide a filesystem path to RELPATH, not a web URL.

The long answer is that when you use a web URL to include a PHP file, the PHP file will be treated like an external source. It will be called remotely, executed in a process of its own, and return the results. A constant defined previously can not have an effect in this remote resource.

If `http://www.saint57records.com/` is on a different server, you'll have to pass RELPATH to it some other way, e.g. through a GET variable (which you'd have to sanitize with `htmlentities()` prior to use.) However, including content from a remote server in this way isn't good practice. It'll slow down your page as it'll make an expensive web request. If the target server is down, your page will time out.

Comment: how do I find the filesystem path, I was thinking it was something like /home/user/public_html/ but that didnt seem to work. I had my username in the user part

Comment: @MichaelStClair the easiest way to find the filesystem path is actually to provoke an error: `<?php dsfadsfads(); ?>` and look at the error message (provided error reporting is on); `echo __DIR__;` will do the job, too

Comment: It is not finding the file, it now prints this <a href="/"><img style="margin:10px;" src="/home4/saintfiv/public_html/images/logo.png" width="60px"/></a>

Comment: I passed the url to the page through a variable and that did it

Comment: @Michael for the image you need to use a web path, just the include_once needs a filesystem path